# What happen if I copy data from a Full Disk Encrypted to another computer?

Tags: encryption

I have an Ubuntu OS in my machine with Full disk encrypted from installation, then I copy a data file (eg. music file or image file) to another computer by a USB, is that file will be encrypted or decrypted before Ubuntu copy it to my USB?

Answer (score 2):

When you login to Ubuntu your disks are automaticly decrypted. So when you copy files on external storage they are decrypted.

Comment: It decrypted a whole disk or just system file? If it decrypt a whole disk so I thought it would be a heavy process?

Comment: You must specify exact method you used to "Full disk encrypt", so I can give you a correct answer.

Comment: I use the check box "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security" and "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation." during installation

Comment: By enabling that options you enable complete encryption of your Ubuntu partitions on your hard drive. So it decrypts all Ubuntu partitions on your disk.

Comment: The whole disk is not decrypted when you log in... the data is decrypted on the fly as you read it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer with enough precision. @psusi answered correctly.